# Error handling and validation param

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, error-handling

I writes application using WEB API 2.0.
I have dilema about how to handle error.

Each **api method** was wrapped with `try-catch` block , and the catch block will return Error reponse to client.

The overall project structure is `API - BL - DATA ACCESS`.

I want your opnion about error handling and validation param.

1. Generally, Why not to wrapp every method with `try-catch` block?
2. Every method in BL and DAL make validation to input param (NULL/empty string) and if one of these not valid so `ArgumentNullException` was raised.

   The BL method are public and they can be called not only from API layer.

Thanks

Comment: 1. It does not make sense to wrap each api method with try-catch. That's what for error handlers were invented. It will allow to have your handling logic in one place. And your api methods won't be responsible for that which is good.

Comment: @sleepwalker can you please be more speciefic, how I need to handle error , instead of use try-catch in each api method?

Comment: 2. If each your layer is going to be used outside of your layers - it makes sense to have that validation logic at BL and DAL. Ideally, when we talk about validation - it should be hosted at least at API & BL layer. That's to allow determine and throw as soon as possible and let that layers be independent. Your error handler at API layer can then transform your exceptions to bad request results with needed level of details.

Comment: Instead of using try-catch in each method - it's better to use exception filters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling or global exception handler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling